# Regresar una cadena con formato

Tags: java

Estoy creando una función que convierte minutos en horas y minutos, pero lo estoy haciendo de esta manera:

```
public String duracion(int tiempo) {
  int horas = tiempo / 60;
  int minutos = tiempo % 60;
  return horas + " hrs. " + minutos + " min.";
}
```

lo que quiero es devolver esta cadena:

```
  return ("%d:%02d", horas, minutos);
```

Pero me marca el error:

> Syntax error on token "return", Name expected after this token

Pero si uso la expresión `("%d:%02d", horas, minutos)` con `System.out.println` si funciona, pero no quiero una función `void`, quiero que regrese la cadena de texto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar, no creo que te funcione esto:

```
System.out.println("%d:%02d", horas, minutos)
```

Ya que el método println en ningún caso acepta 3 parámetros, en todo caso supongo que lo habrás hecho con el método `printf`

Aclarado eso, el método `duracion` devuelve un String, y tu estás devolviendo una expresión que no es válida en Java, estás devolviendo 3 cosas separadas por espacios y todo ello metido entre paréntesis.

Entiendo que todo esto lo estás haciendo para poder hacer algo así:

```
System.out.printf(duracion(miTiempo));
```

Lo que pasa es que en Java no le puedes pasar 3 parámetros a una función así como así. Tienes varias opciones.

Puedes hacer varias funciones, por cada parámetro que le vayas a pasar a printf, por ejemplo:

```
System.out.printf(getPatron(), getHoras(), getMinutos());
```

También puedes hacer una función que devuelva tres cosas diferentes en una lista en un array, por ejemplo:

```
Object[] duracion = getDuracion(miTiempo);
String patron = (String) duracion[0];
Integer hora = (Integer) duracion[1];
Integer minuto = (Integer) duracion[2];
Sysem.out.printf(patron, hora, minuto);
```

También puedes devolver un objeto que contenga los tres parámetros:

```
public class Duracion {
   private final String patron;
   private final Integer hora;
   private final Integer minuto;
   public Duracion(String patron, Integer hora, Integer minuto) {
      this.duracion = duracion;
      this.hora = hora;
      this.minuto = minuto;
   }
   public String getPatron() {
     return this.hora;
   }
   public Integer getHora() {
     return this.hora;
   }
   public Integer getHora() {
     return this.hora;
   }
}

public Duracion getDuracion(int tiempo) {
  String patron = "%d:%02d";
  int horas = tiempo / 60;
  int minutos = tiempo % 60;
  Duracion duracion = new Duracion(patron, horas, minuts);
  return duracion;
}

Duracion duracion = getDuracion(miTempo);
String patron = duracion.getPatron();
Integer hora = duracion.getHora();
Integer minuto = duracion.getMinuto();
System.out.printf(patron, hora, minuto);
```

También puedes devolver el string ya formateado, y no llamar a printf, sino a println:

```
public String duracion(int tiempo) {
  int horas = tiempo / 60;
  int minutos = tiempo % 60;
  return String.format("%d:%02d", horas, minutos);
}

System.out.println(duracion(miTiempo));
```

La función format funciona de forma parecida a printf, pero no lo imprime directamente, pero lo guarda en una cadena, y luego haces con ella lo que necesites.

- String.format: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)

Comment: Sí, tienes razón. era la función `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

Estas olvidando usar el metodo String.format

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String result = duracion(3600*5);
    System.out.println(result);
}

public  static String duracion(int tiempo) {
    int horas = tiempo / 60;
    int minutos = tiempo % 60;
    return String.format("%d:%02d", horas, minutos);
}
```